# Divide Data Frame Python

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am pretty new user of Jupiter Notebook and struggling to find a solution of the case below :
I am having a df with 177 rows containing Country Name and Number of Bookings ( two columns in total)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEUVT.png)

My desire is to plot as bar chart the Top 10 countries in terms of number of reservations (quantile 0.9 yields 650 bookings) along with all others merged in one 'other countries' category.
How could I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

even I am new to python programming.

According to me, you can do it by first sorting the dataframe based on col:"Bookings", just take top 10 rows from the sorted df and add the booking values of rest of the rows then replacing them with a row value: "Others".

1. Sorting:
   [pandas.DataFrame.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

> df_Sorted = df.sort_values(['Bookings'], ascending=False,
> ignore_index=True)[:10]

2. Sum:

> df_Sorted.loc[10] = ["Others", df.sort_values(['Bookings'],
> ascending=False)["Bookings"][10:].sum()]

3. Plot:

> df_Sorted.plot(kind = 'bar')

There might be a better way of doing it.
I hope this was of help to you!

Comment: Hi @faiz__shahid I like your approach. I have modified the df meanwhile and now I have four columns : "country" (name of country),  'not_canceled' ,  'canceled' and   'total_bookings'. How should I modify your code so that be able to complete point 2 (Sum) of your previous reply ?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using the [df.nlargest()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) method provided by pandas. This returns a dataframe with the n largest values of a particular column.

Getting the 10 largest countries and plotting them in a bar chart could be done this way:

```
df.nlargest(10, "Bookings")
df.plot.bar(x="Country")
```

An example with a smaller dataframe for which we want to plot the number of bookings for the largest 3 countries looks like:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"Country": ["PRT", "GE", "NL", "USA", "GB"], "Bookings": [55, 66, 12, 45, 44]})
df = df.nlargest(3, "Bookings")
df.plot.bar(x="Country")
```

This results in the following bar plot:

[image]